# copy data from one partitioned table to another new partitioned table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

Need to copy data from one partitioned table to another new partitioned table tried this method but doesn't work

```
create table if not exists box_db.table_1 partitioned by (sch_ky, at_ky, date) as select * from sand_db.table_2
```

Also tried

```
create table box_db.table_1 (id bigint, sch_val int, at_val int) partitioned by (sch_ky int, at_ky int, date string)
```

and insert data into it

```
insert into box_db.table_1 select * from sand_db.table_2
```

but both doesn't work

Comment: *tried this method but doesn't work* Do not try to create your own syntax - server won't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

create the table with new partition values. Then to insert into a partitioned table, you need to -

1. mention partition column if you are inserting in table with dynamic partition.

```
insert into box_db.table_1 partition(id, sch_val, at_val) select ..., id,sch_val, at_val from sand_db.table_2 -- make sure  last columns matches to last columns in select clause
```

or 2. mention partition value if you are inserting in table with static partition.

```
insert into box_db.table_1 partition(id=1, sch_val=2, at_val=3) select ...  from sand_db.table_2 -- make sure  all columns in select matches to the columns in table
```